# wrong warning message in switch/case, `Case is already handled by previous patterns; consider removing it.`

Tags: swift

```
let a: String! = "hello, world"
let c: Any = a

switch c {
case Optional<Any>.some(let value):
    print(value)
case Optional<Any>.none: // Case is already handled by previous patterns; consider removing it
    print(c)
}
```

I have the code above, the second case is obviously not handled by previous patterns, why I have this warning message, is this a bug of swift ?

Comment: It is the bug [SR-6975](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6975), but it has already been fixed by [#15264](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/15264), and will be fixed in Swift 4.2.

Comment: Please, don't use `Any`. Always cast it to the specific type.

Comment: @Sulthan I would like to not use `Any`, but sometimes we just don't have choice, for example, when you want to set parameters for you http request, how would you declare without any?
`public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]` that's what Alamofire do for the parameters.

Comment: @JIEWANG That's true but I am pretty sure you don't have to switch over those parameters.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah,  the switch just for fun   :)

Comment: Though note that relying on the `switch` to do an actual dynamic cast rather than just optional promotion is a bit iffy IMO – currently IIRC, `as` patterns (you get an implicit one in your example) always perform a dynamic cast, but such patterns that really perform coercions (such as the one in your example) really shouldn't. If the compiler were to treat it as an actual coercion, you'd (currently) get optional promotion without digging into the value of the `Any`.